# Urdu to urdu using SpeechRecognizer and RecognitionListener

Tags: java, android

I am working on urdu to urdu speech recognition. But all i have get roman urdu in return.

```
private void startListening() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "Urdu");
    final SpeechRecognizer recognizer = SpeechRecognizer
            .createSpeechRecognizer(this.getApplicationContext());
    RecognitionListener listener = new RecognitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle results) {
            ArrayList<String> voiceResults = results
                    .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

            if (voiceResults != null) {
                tv_output2.setText(voiceResults.get(0));
            }
            if (voiceResults == null) {
                System.out.println("No voice results");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Printing matches: ");
                for (String match : voiceResults) {
                    System.out.println(match);
                }
            }
        }


    };
    recognizer.setRecognitionListener(listener);
    recognizer.startListening(intent);
```

I getting response "tum kaisa hoa" instead of "تم کیسی ہو"

Comment: Use "ur" language ISO 639-1 Code instead "Urdu"

Comment: Dear @AnasMehar i have tried "ur" still getting the same result.

Comment: have u got the answer?

Answer (score 0):

use it like this:

```
    speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(getContext());
    speechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "ur");
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, true);
```